# org-capture: use without indirect buffer

Tags: org-mode, org-capture

Is there a way to enter capture text without the indirect buffer after `C-c c`?

So, after pressing `C-c c` the `:LOGBOOK:`is directly filled with `- Note taken on...` and I can continue capturing text in that place.

For example: In an org-mode buffer I'am pressing `C-c c` on a title and no indirect buffer opens up, instead the cursor jumps to the `:LOGBOOK:` property after a newly created `- Note taken on...` entry, where the input can be continued.

Comment: You *are* capturing text in "that place", even *with* the indirect buffer showing. I'm not sure what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: NickD, I what to see my last entries when I'am typing a new one

Comment: You can display the base buffer in another window: `(display-buffer (buffer-base-buffer))` - untested.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately `(display-buffer)` returns `nil` inside the org-capture buffer.

Comment: `display-buffer` takes an argument: which buffer to display and returns a window, the window in which the buffer is displayed. When you are in the indirect buffer of the capture, type `ESC-ESC : (display-buffer (buffer-base-buffer))` - there are two function calls here: `buffer-base-buffer` is called and returns the base buffer of the indirect buffer, then `display-buffer` is called with that buffer as argument to display it in a window.

Comment: You can simply widen your capture buffer with `C-x n w`.

Comment: NickD, thats what I do, `M-: (display-buffer (buffer-base-buffer))` and I'am getting _display-buffer: Wrong type argument: stringp, nil_ because `(display-buffer)` returns `nil`

Comment: gusbrs, widen does nothing wit org mode version 9.4.6.

Comment: Both `(display-buffer (buffer-base-buffer))` and `C-x n w` work for me. Not sure what's going wrong (maybe you can describe your process precisely and add it to your question so we can try to reproduce), but there is definitely something wrong. Can you try with `emacs -q`? Maybe there is something screwy in your init file.

Comment: NickD, thanks again for your time. Tried `emacs -q` without success, upgraded emacs from 26.3 to 27.1 with same results: `nil` for `(buffer-base-buffer)` and `C-x n w` without effect.
Added more information in above question anyway.